# Use Flash Message in Blade template

Tags: laravel

I have controller and function like below

```
class UserController extends Controller
    {

        public function index(){
            $title = trans('app.users');
            $users = User::orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->paginate(20);
             $users_count = User::count();
            return view('admin.users', compact('title', 'users', 'users_count'));
     }
}
```

I have a blade template named `flash_msg.blade.php` which has below content.

```
@if(session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {!! session('success') !!}
        </div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {!! session('error') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

I included below code in my blade template.

```
@include('admin.flash_msg')
```

How can I use this ? Which code should I write in controller to get the result of Flash Message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('admin.users', compact('title', 'users', 'users_count'))->with('success', ' updated!'); //for success message
```

just go through this link...to get a more clear view

https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 1):

While returning to a view you can't send a session flush message. If you write like

```
return view('admin.users', compact('title', 'users', 'users_count'))->with('success', ' Message!');
```

This won't show the message in

```
@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {!! session('success') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

However you can use the success as a variable `$success` and do whatever you want to do with the variable.

Well while redirecting to a route or a url or back, you can use session flush message like

```
return redirect()
            ->route('your.route')
            ->with('success', 'Added Successfully');
```

And you will get the flush data now in

```
@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {!! session('success') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: How to do this "However you can use the success as a variable $success and do whatever you want to do with the variable." ? Your reply is not clear.

Comment: i mean you can use it like a variable in blade. `{{ $success }}`

Comment: How can I use this `return redirect()
            ->route('your.route')
            ->with('success', 'Added Successfully');` with `return view()` ?

Comment: you can't do this with return view.